# Checking text with Selenium that doesn't appear in the HTML

Tags: c#, selenium

I need to write a test that checks some fields are updated with the right information when a button is clicked.

The problem is that when the information changes, nothing in the HTML changes.

Is there an alternative to Element.Text to achieve this? As that method doesn't work.

I'm writing my scripts in c# and using Selenium 3.7.0

Steps to automate:

1. Click a button to draw data from a database and populate fields on the page
2. Check that these fields now contain the correct data from the database

Comment: `information changes` implies `HTML changes`. Can you update the question with the _Manual Steps_ you are trying to _Automate_ along with the relevant _HTML_?

Answer (score 0):

Start with clicking the element that needs to be clicked to populate your fields. Then you can do something like this:

```
IWebElement demoDiv = driver.FindElement(By.Id("demo-div"));

string textInElement = demoDiv.GetAttribute("innerHTML"));
```

.. then use the textInElement variable as you like. What you probably want to do is to make a comparison/assert with your expected value.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this, using Element.GetAttribute("value") returns data within a textbox, whereas I thought it would be looking for the value attribute attached to the element.